# Detect in content script when sidePanel is opened or closed?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Can I detect in a content script if the sidePanel is open or closed?

When the side panel loads I could get the tabId and save to storage that the side panel was open.

In sidepanel:

```
const tabs = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });
chrome.storage.session.set({ [`TAB_${tabs[0].id}`]: 'sidepanel-open' });
```

However I'm not aware of any event for when the side panel closes. I could use an interval to message the sidepanel, and if no response comes back assume that its closed. Feels quite hacky though:

In content script:

```
  setInterval(() => {
    chrome.runtime
      .sendMessage({ ['sidepanel-check']: true })
      .then((msgRes) => {
        if (msgRes !== true) {
          chrome.storage.session.set({
            [`${TAB_}${tabId}`]: 'sidepanel-closed',
          });
        }
      });
  }, 1000);
```

In sidepanel:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (request['sidepanel-check'] === true) {
    sendResponse(true);
  }
});
```

Comment: Use port's onDisconnect.addListener in the content script and chrome.tabs.connect in the side panel, see [port messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/#connect).